# Birt export the xlsx issue

Tags: birt

I am using birt 4.3.1 so by default spudsoft emitter is available in birt ,using that emitter i am generating xlsx document but below exception is raised, i am using birt 4.3.1 runtime jar .the problem mentioned in the below path also but i am not understand that one https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398774

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Report engine fails to 
initialize uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsxEmitter emitter, please 
make sure required libraries for this emitter are installed.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
```

Comment: Can you post your tried code part for figure out the issue?

Comment: There are plenty of questions on SO dealing with a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Dare to search and read them?

Comment: It was Birt issue in 4.3.1 if any one birt expertise please help me for java side every thing okay ,because when generate xls it's works fine the problem is when generate xlsx then the above exception raised

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose the problem is with birt not java

Comment: Well ... I reopened beacuse no other question about a `NoClassDefFoundError` explicitely mentioned BIRT. I do not have an answer myself, but it seems that there are other BIRT dependencies that do not include an Apache POI.

Comment: xls will work fine but Xlsx wont work with native-excel-emitter. you need to add dependency uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsxEmitter for XLSX